# Flutter Nested bottom sheet or slide up panel

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

What is the best way to build a "nested bottom sheet" which behaves like this:
https://dribbble.com/shots/14139422-Mobile-banking-app-interactions?

Do I have to use `NestedScrollView` or `CustomScrollView`, or a completely different approach?

**Update :**

This is my result using `SlidingUpPanel`, but I still have two problems:

1. When sliding up the panel, the green and red containers stay behind the panel and do not scroll out of view at the top.
2. In landscape mode the containers are higher than the device, so this approach does not work. I need the panel to be attached to the bottom of the containers, so it is only visible when scrolling down.

Code:

```
SafeArea(
  child: Scaffold(
    body: SlidingUpPanel(
      minHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 479,
      maxHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 79,
      panel: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [Text('Sliding Panel')],
        ),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Container(
              height: 100,
              color: Colors.green,
            ),
            Container(
              height: 300,
              color: Colors.red,
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Result:

[image: Result]

Comment: Flutter support nested navigation.

Comment: Welcome to flutter where there is a widget for almost everything. DraggableScrollableSheet might be just the widget you need https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hgw819mL_78

Comment: @ByteMe How do I implement it to be nested in the scrollview and not placed above it?

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is a Widget for what you want to do, since there is a widget for everything in Flutter. here is the [link](https://pub.dev/packages/sliding_up_panel) of the package

**NOTE :** you can also set minimum height of the widget when collapsed in order to control how much of the widget you can show when it is collapsed.

**And here is the demo :**

[image]
  [image]